# How to add a conditional statement to assign a value inside C# lambda select list query?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities, google-maps-markers

I have a working lambda query that gets list data for nearby map points.  The `FoodType` value indicates what group the restaurant is part of, like this: `3 - Italian`, `1 - Mexican`, `4 - Indian`.

How can I add a conditional `if` statement to the query that would assign a different colored icon for that map point, based on their `FoodType` value.

I want

`1 - Mexican` to be `Icon = "../Images/red-dot.png"`
`3 - Italian` to be `Icon = "../Images/yellow-dot.png"`
`5 - Asian` to be `Icon = "../Images/blue-dot.png"`

Here is my Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(float latitude, float longitude)
{
    var sourcePoint = CreatePoint(latitude, longitude);    
    var locations = db.Restaurants
        .Where(loc => loc.GeoLocation.Distance(sourcePoint) < 1500)
        .OrderBy(loc => loc.GeoLocation.Distance(sourcePoint))
        .Select(loc => new MapViewModel
        {
            Address = loc.PrimaryAddress1,
            City = loc.PrimaryCity,
            HHName = loc.HHName,
            Age = loc.Age,
            FoodType = loc.FoodType,
            Id = loc.Id,
            Latitude = (float)loc.Latitude,
            Longitude = (float)loc.Longitude,
            Distance = loc.GeoLocation.Distance(sourcePoint),
        })
        .ToList();    
    return Json(locations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my Map code:
(I have even tried setting the map point color inside the script without success)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Index/",
    data: { "latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude, 'address': address },
    dataType: "json",
    position: latLng,
    center: latLng,
    success: function(data) {                            
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.Latitude, value.Longitude);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                icon: "../Images/blue-dot.png",
                title: value.HHname,
                address: value.Address,
                city: value.City,
                food: value.FoodType,
                age: value.Age,
                id: value.id,
                map: map
            });
            var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
            '<div id="siteNotice">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + value.HHName + '</h1>' +
            '<div id="bodyContent">' +
            '<p><b>' + value.FoodType + '</b></p>' +
            '<p>Age:' + value.Age + '</b></p>' +
            '<p><b>' + value.Address + ', ' + value.City + '</b></p>' +
            '<p><a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">More Info' +
            '</a> ' +
            '</p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                maxWidth: 250,                                    
                content: contentString
            });
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        });            
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LINQ-to-Entities or Entity Framework, then you can't use a custom method in the query because the underlying provider expects to be able to translate the query expression directly into SQL.  If you're getting an error saying the method is not recognized, that is why.  You can only use methods that the underlying provider knows how to translate.  With this in mind, there are a few different approaches you could take.

**1. Use the ternary operator to calculate the value**

It's a bit ugly, but it should work because it can be translated to a SQL `CASE` expression.

```
var locations = db.Restaurants
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Select(loc => new MapViewModel
    {
        ...
        FoodType = loc.FoodType,
        Icon = "../Images/" + 
               (loc.FoodType == "1 - Mexican" ? "red" : 
               (loc.FoodType == "3 - Italian" ? "yellow" : "blue")) + 
               "-dot.png",
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

**2. Run the query, then fix up the results before returning it to the client**

This is the usual workaround when you need to run a server-side method to include calculated data in your results and that method is not supported by LINQ-to-Entities.

```
// DB query
var locations = db.Restaurants
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Select(loc => new MapViewModel
    {
        ...
        FoodType = loc.FoodType,
        ...
    })
    .ToList();

// Fix up
foreach (var model in locations)
{
    model.Icon = GetIconForFoodType(model.FoodType);
}

return Json(locations, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**3. Change your data model to include the icon image name in the table**

If the icon name is part of the table data, then there's no translation needed; you can just include it directly in the result.

```
var locations = db.Restaurants
    .Where(...)
    .OrderBy(...)
    .Select(loc => new MapViewModel
    {
        ...
        FoodType = loc.FoodType,
        Icon = "../Images/" + loc.IconName
        ...
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer #1 really helped me out. See my answer below for implementation which works perfectly. Brian's is the answer but I add mine for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

For readability and reusability write a separate function that converts the `FoodType` value to its corresponding icon.

```
string GetIconForFoodType(string foodType)
{
    //Your function
}
```

Then when creating your `MapViewModel`, assign

```
Icon = GetIconForFoodType(loc.FoodType)
```

Comment: After attempting to use your suggestion, I am getting and error message that LINQ to Entities is not recognizing the method.  Could it be that LINQ requires the whole query expression to be translated to a server query, and therefore I can't call an outside method within it?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer #1 really helped me. In case it helps anyone here is my implementation which works perfectly below. It's what as he suggested.

```
@Html.DropDownList("TaxonId", Model.Taxa.Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                        {
                            Text = i.TaxonName,
                            Value = i.Id.ToString(),
                            Selected = (i.Id == @Model.Site.TaxonId) ? true : false
                        }),
                        "Select taxon",
                        new { @class = "form-control edited", required = String.Empty })
```